# Best bound of complex Hilbert transform

Tags: cv.complex-variables, fourier-analysis, integral-transforms

It is well-known (see Grafakos' *Classical Fourier Analysis*, Exercise 5.1.12) that if $f$ is a real valued $L^p(\mathbb R)$ function and $1<p<2$ , then we have the following inequality:
$$
\|Hf\|_{L^p(\mathbb R)}\leq A_p\|f\|_{L^p(\mathbb R)},
$$
where $A_p=\tan \frac {\pi}{2p}$. Moreover, this bound is sharp.

A nice and elegant proof and also be found in [https://faculty.missouri.edu/~grafakosl/preprints/pichorides.pdf](https://faculty.missouri.edu/%7Egrafakosl/preprints/pichorides.pdf).

However, I was wondering if this bound is also true for complex valued functions $f$. The proof above used the fact that if $f$ is real valued, then the real part and the imaginary part of the integral
$$
\frac i \pi\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac {f(t)}{z-t}dt
$$
converges to $f(x)$ and $Hf(x)$ respectively, as $y\to 0^+$, where $z=x+iy$. For complex valued $f$, this is no longer true.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer myself; it is a result of Theorem 5.5.1 of Grafakos’ *Classical Fourier Analysis*. The result we need is that if a linear operator maps real valued functions to real valued functions and has real L^p-L^p operator norm bounded by A, then its complex operator norm is also bounded by A.